# PHOTO FIELD IN EASYADMIN IS NOT SHOWING

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony2-easyadmin

I am trying to display some images in my bundle (using easyadmin bundle) & symfony 3.4
However, for some reason, the photos aren't showing.
here's my code:
in config.yml:

```
       Employee:
        class: BackofficeBundle\Entity\Employee
        role_prefix: ROLE_EMPLOYEE_MANAGER
        list:
            fields:
                - id
                - Name
                - { property: 'photo', label: 'EMPLOYEE AVATAR', type: 'image' , base_path: '/images/' }
```

in my Employee entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=500)
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="500k", mimeTypes={"image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/GIF"})
 */
private $photo;
```

in my EmployeeType.php

```
 $builder->add('photo', FileType::class, array('data_class'=>null, 'required'=>false
    ));
```

The photo aren't showing in the List page and when i click on the edit i get this error :

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this natively with symfony and easyadmin only, i'm affraid that you have to use vichuploaderbundle to handle image with easyadmin, or use Transformer to obtain image from filename (or path).

Vichuploaderbundle doc : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/vichuploaderbundle.html

Comment: @Lounis i just tried it but i got another error

Comment: i'm getting **An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[Semantical Error] line 0, col 75 near 'photo DESC': Error: Class BackofficeBundle\Entity\Employee has no field or association named photo").** although i updated my database

Comment: it seems to be an syntax matter on your entity annotation, i can't help you for this sorry.

Comment: solved it :) thank you @Lounis the solution was to change to vichuploaderbundle as u said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, please consider using VichUploadBundle https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/vichuploaderbundle.html